# check the oval shape position vba

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

Dears;

I would like to thank you for your support.
I'm in writing VBA macro to draw and color the shapes, I've got to step when I need to draw the shapes based on another position shapes, for that I need to know how I can know the shape position by its name
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Shapes class to get a shapes position (`left` and `top`).  If you need their right or bottom position add `left` and `width` or `top` and `height`.

```
Sub GetShapePosition()
    Debug.Print "Left: " & ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Left
    Debug.Print "Width: " & ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Width
    Debug.Print "Right: " & ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Left + ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Width
    
    Debug.Print "Top: " & ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Top
    Debug.Print "Height: " & ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Height
    Debug.Print "Bottom: " & ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Top + ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Width
End Sub
```